# How to resize and rotage image while orientation change in android

Tags: android

I am taking picture using camera in landscape mode .I am displaying picture in potrait mode also how to display picture properly in all modes can anybody give example

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29). Hope this provide the data you need